# What could cause staining in a toilet bowl?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, cleaning

I have one toilet that works fine, but the bottom of the bowl looks like those you see in gasoline station restrooms.  I can scrub it with a toilet brush and a dose of bleach and most of it clears up, but the bottom still looks stained.  Is it that the china has gotten old and is retaining stains?  A woman told me that it is because of the wax ring, but I doubt that.  I was thinking may a paint store would have an epoxy that would fix the stain.   Would that be the way to go?

Comment: The wax ring has nothing to do with what's in the bowl. Do you have iron in your water? How old is the toilet? Replacing it is a better plan than trying to coat it. They're not that expensive, and installation isn't difficult in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Many times older toilets have been cleaned with harsh chemicals that damages the surface. It ends up being cheaper and will look better to replace the toilet than dry it out clean coat let coating dry and find it needs a repeat in a couple of months.